# Keep connection alive even if physically not connected for a while?

Tags: networking, windows-11, lan, smb

So here is the scenario I have a laptop that I use with a LAN cable connected to it to my PS2 on which I play OPL games stored on my SMB.

However I also lift that laptop of the table to put on my lap (since I also do work on it) and the LAN port on it is one of those half ones with a spring loaded piece on the bottom - the cable itself is brand new with a good plastic on the top (not broken) but even still it rotates and can easily physically disconnect when I move the laptop around.

When that happens I need to restart the PS2 from the button.

While OPL can potentially be the issue here I figure it can't be improved much due to PS2 being old so I was thinking instead if like there is some way to make Windows wait for connection and restore the SMB "session" (if there is such a thing) after a physical connection is present again. I would prefer if there is an already existing Windows feature (built-in) but a third-party solution or script is probably fine too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @John It's not the issue the laptop is just cheap I guess but nevertheless irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate this indeed answers my question.